# Add image to JPanel within JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I have this code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Interface {

        private JPanel panel;
        private JPanel buttonPane;
        private JLabel label;
        private JLabel label2;
        private JTextField textfield;
        private JTextField textfield2;
        private JTextField textfield3;
        private JTextField textfield4;
        private JTextField textfield5;
        private JButton button;
        private JButton button2;
        private JButton button3;
        private JButton button4;
        private JButton button5;
        private JButton button6;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Interface();
        }

        public Interface() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vormen");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 300);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            panel = new JPanel();
            buttonPane = new JPanel();
            button = new JButton("cirkel");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/cirkel.png"));
            panel.add(label3);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        buttonPane.add(button);
        buttonPane.add(button2);
        buttonPane.add(button3);


        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

However, if I run it, the image doesn't appear.

Why is that? I'm new to Java so I make little mistakes like this very easily.

I have tried several options but none of them worked out for me.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```
JLabel label3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/images/cirkel.png"));
```

Don't use `/images/...`. The leading "/" tells java to look at the root directory of your drive.

I'm guessing your "images" directory is in your source directory so you should be using:

```
JLabel label3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/cirkel.png"));
```

> I'm new to Java so I make little mistakes like this very easily.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for better examples of how to load images and working examples to give you a better structure to your program.

The idea is to start with a working program and learn from the structure of that program. Then make small changes. If it stops working then you know what you changed and what caused the problem.

Comment: "images" directory is in my source directory indeed. But the program still doesn't show the image...

Comment: The code you posted is still wrong. Did you read the tutorial and use the more flexible way or reading images as shown in the example code? Start with working code!!!

Comment: I still can't figure out how to make this work.... Can you please post an example?

Comment: I gave you an example. The example is in the Swing tutorial.