# Adding an image to JPanel within JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to make an JFrame, with a JPanel inside it and an image inside a JLabel. Then by adding the JLabel to the JPanel it must work right? However, this is the way it's done on docs.oracle.com...

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Interface {

        private JPanel panel;
        private JPanel buttonPane;
        private JLabel label;
        private JLabel label2;
        private JTextField textfield;
        private JTextField textfield2;
        private JTextField textfield3;
        private JTextField textfield4;
        private JTextField textfield5;
        private JButton button;
        private JButton button2;
        private JButton button3;
        private JButton button4;
        private JButton button5;
        private JButton button6;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Interface();
        }

        public Interface() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vormen");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 300);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            panel = new JPanel();
            buttonPane = new JPanel();
            button = new JButton("cirkel");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/cirkel.png"));
            panel.add(label3);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        buttonPane.add(button);
        buttonPane.add(button2);
        buttonPane.add(button3);


        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that your application can't access images/cirkel.png file. Use absolute path to make sure it will find it, or even better, find some tutorial about resources and how to deal with them. Then put that file as a resource to your application.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that you were adding the image components in an ActionListener -- your faulty indentations threw me off (please fix this). For this, you're better off adding the components, here the JLabel to the main GUI at the beginning, and then simply setting its icon within the ActionListener. If you already know the size of the image at the app start, then it's often a good idea to set in an ImageIcon with an empty image of the correct size on app startup.

Comment: `find some tutorial about resources and how to deal with them.` - answer was already given yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784690/add-image-to-jpanel-within-jlabel/30784800#30784800. It get annoying when the OP doesn't read the information provided.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @camickr. Frustrating when this happens.

Comment: He is obviously a new guy. Don't be harsh. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can't find the ""images/cirkel.png". You have few alternatives:

- Use an absolute path (like I do in the modified code below).
- Use resources (there are hundreds of good tutorials how to do this).

I use absolute path for quick hacks. For anything serious I would chose resources as they are bundled with your application.

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel buttonPane;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    private JTextField textfield3;
    private JTextField textfield4;
    private JTextField textfield5;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JButton button6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Interface();
    }

    public Interface() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vormen");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("cirkel");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Use absolute path here:
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/tyrion/circle.png"));
                panel.add(label);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();

            }
        });

        buttonPane.add(button);
        // buttonPane.add(button2);
        // buttonPane.add(button3);

        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's usually much better to use resources than to use absolute paths.

Comment: I think every Java programmer would agree. However, using resources means spending extra time bundling files, etc. Using absolute paths is quicker when someone wants to do some quick tests...

Comment: every code lines in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` together == `label.setIcon(IconCachedInLocalVariable)`

Comment: `It's usually much better to use resources than to use absolute paths.` - already suggested in the OP's original question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784690/add-image-to-jpanel-within-jlabel/30784800#30784800. I see the OP hasn't taken the time to read the tutorial and restructure the code. The code is still not executed on the EDT. Wonder how he expects to learn if he doesn't read tutorials?